# Custom Format in SAS

Tags: sas

I am looking to create a custom format in SAS which will convert continent codes such as NA, EU and AF to North America, Europe and Africa. Everything has been set up and I have SAS reading in a .csv file containing the countries and their continent codes, and I can print a table showing each country with its respective country code. Now I just want to convert the code to a continent name using a custom format. So far I have the following (I have missed out all the DATA step as this works fine):

```
LIBNAME newlib 'C:\Users\C*****\Documents\My WPS Files';

PROC FORMAT lib = newlib;
VALUE $cont
    'AS' = 'Asia'
    'EU' = 'Europe'
    'NA' = 'North America'
    'SA' = 'South America'
    'AF' = 'Africa'
    'OC' = 'Oceania'
    '' = 'Unknown';
 RUN;

 PROC PRINT DATA = newlib.life_ex (OBS = 10) NOOBS;
     TITLE 'Top 10 Life Expectancies in 2010';
     VAR Country YR2010 Continent;
     FORMAT Continent$cont.;
 RUN;
```

If I run this, I get the following error.

```
2947        FORMAT Continent$cont.;
                       ^
ERROR: Format $cont was not found or could not be loaded
```

I don't understand this as I am following exact steps I have previously used in other SAS programs which worked fine, but this one won't execute. If I remove the FORMAT Continent$cont. line, the program runs perfectly without error but obviously my codes are not converted. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
options insert=(fmtsearch=newlib);
```

This code tells SAS where to find the format (as it wasn't stored in the default WORK library).

It needs to executed *before* the format is used, so that SAS knows where to search for it.  So in this case, before the `proc print` step.

If the above option does not work (it should) try:

```
options fmtsearch=(newlib work);
```

The problem with this approach is that you have to identify and build the entire search path (rather than insert a new path at the start)

Comment: I thought by mentioning the library in the PROC PRINT step it would follow suit as I did it in my previous program. I am unsure exactly where I need to put this OPTIONS command.

Comment: I updated the answer, it needs to go after the library definition and before the place where the format is called.  The reason it's not available automatically is that you are using the `lib=` option in `proc format` to save the format as a permanent format in a specific library.  That library is not automatically added to the format search path (think in terms of scalability - if you have millions of format definitions you wouldn't want them all defined and searchable all of the time)

Comment: if it worked previously, you must have had that library in your search path.  I tested this in SAS Studio and it works fine..

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarity, I understand that more now. I have tried using the line you suggested and get the following: _ERROR: System option "INSERT" is not known, ERROR: Value for system option FMTSEARCH requires parentheses, ERROR: Found ")" when expecting a name._

Comment: I added a new approach - `options fmtsearch=(newlib work);`, try that.  I see from your original code you are using WPS.  In my experience they are pretty good at fixing these kind of issues, I suggest getting in touch and asking them to fix this feature, as it should work as described.

Comment: I've followed your new approach and it works perfectly, thank you.